# System variables aren't evaluated in Windows command prompt, user variables are

Tags: windows, environment-variables, command-prompt

I would like to be able to `cd` into a folder that is added to a system as a system variable in Windows 11. Here is a visual representation of the problem:[image]

As you can see, windows command prompt is able to "resolve" variables from the "User variables" section of the Environment variables configuration in Windows, however variables from the "System variables" aren't.

I need to `cd` into %VS140COMNTOOLS% folder but as you can see it won't be resolved by the command prompt. Is this by design?

VS140COMNTOOLS also doesn't appear in `set` output.

How can I navigate into %VS140COMNTOOLS%?

Comment: That's not how it works.  That variable is *normally* only defined after running the Developer Command Prompt, having it defined in the machine default would be a big mistake.  That only produces builds that don't reproduce on another machine.  Having an early taste of such a mishap is hard to explain from the question, maybe it is a good thing it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System variables and user vars end up in a single environment block. When expanding env vars, there's no concept of user/system. User vars override system vars.

Also: each process gets its own *copy* of env vars which is resolved when the process launches. Therefore, if a process appears to be "missing" an env var, one of the following happened:

1. The variable was set *after* the process launched. For example maybe this command prompt was open during the installation of something that created an env var. You'll need to re-launch the command prompt to get the var.
2. OR, the process modified it / removed it.

Comment: It worked after restart, so there must have been some "event" in my instance that have removed that particular variable from the "set" list. This answer is absolutely correct and provides good details on the question aspects. Thank you.